# Comparing record type in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables like:

Table one columns: `PRD_ID, COMP, TD1, TD2, TD3`

Table two columns: `ACC_ID, COMP, TD1, TD2, TD3`

Above account_id is mapped to `PRD_ID`.
I want to compare whether for any `COMP`, any of the values among `TD1`, `TD1` or `TD3` has been changed. I will give sample data.

```
Table 1: PRD_ID   COMP   TD1   TD2   TD3
          T       A      Y     Y     Y
          T       B      Y     N     N
Table 2: ACC_ID   COMP   TD1   TD2   TD3 
          S       A      N     N     Y
          S       B      Y     N     N
```

So, between above two tables, for COMP A values have been changed. I should get some count or values so that I can use that in IF condition to do some operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this data is stored in tables, you don't need record type. You can use `MINUS`:

```
for i in (select COMP, TD1, TD2, TD3 from table1
           minus
          select COMP, TD1, TD2, TD3 from table2) loop
  -- do something with changed records
end loop;
```

If there is no changes, code in the cycle won't execute. This code will show rows from the `table1`, which differs from rows in `table2`. If you need rows from `table2`, revert the SQL query:

```
for i in (select COMP, TD1, TD2, TD3 from table2
           minus
          select COMP, TD1, TD2, TD3 from table1) loop
  -- do something with changed records
end loop;
```

If you want to use explicit cursors:

```
declare
  cursor c1 is
    select COMP, TD1, TD2, TD3 from table1
     minus
    select COMP, TD1, TD2, TD3 from table2;
  c1_row c1%rowtype;
begin
  open c1;
  loop
    fetch c1 into c1_row;
    exit when c1%notfound;
    -- do something
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitry suggested, you probably don't need to compare records.

For completeness, if you really need to compare records, then you need to implement comparison by yourselve (field by field), as Oracle doesn't support testing record types for equality or inequality.

See Oracle Documentation: [Record Comparisons](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS496)

Example of record comparison function (`test_equal`):

```
declare
  cursor c1 is
    select 'R' PRD_ID, 'A' COMP, 'Y' TD1, 'Y' TD2, 'Y' TD3 from dual;
  cursor c2 is
    select 'S' ACC_ID, 'A' COMP, 'Y' TD1, 'Y' TD2, 'Y' TD3 from dual;
  c1_row c1%rowtype;
  c2_row c2%rowtype;
  FUNCTION test_equal (c1_row c1%rowtype, c2_row c1%rowtype) RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF  c1_row.td1 = c2_row.td1
    AND c1_row.td2 = c2_row.td2
    AND c1_row.td3 = c2_row.td3
    THEN RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
  END;
begin
  open c1;
  open c2;
  loop
    fetch c1 into c1_row;
    exit when c1%notfound;

    fetch c2 into c2_row;
    exit when c2%notfound;

    if test_equal(c1_row, c2_row)
    then
      -- do something 
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```